# Calling LINQ with predicate expression through ILGenerator

Tags: c#, linq, cil

I am trying to compile a DynamicMethod by emitting IL at runtime. I would like it to perform the following:

```
array.OrderByDesc( /* Select Field/Property Expression*/ ).ToArray();
```

The method that compiles the DynamicMethod has a `FieldInfo` variable that I would like to use for the expression that `OrderByDesc` requires.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public static FilterDelegate<T> CreateDelegate<T>( Expression<Func<T, double>> expression )
{
  var field = expression.GetFieldInfo();// Extension, gets FieldInfo from expression
  ...
  il.Emit( OpCodes.Ldloc_1 ); // Loads an array (T[])
  il.Emit( OpCodes.Call, typeof( Enumerable ).GetMethod( nameof( Enumerable.OrderByDescending ), new Type[0]).MakeGenericMethod( typeof( T ) ) );
  il.Emit( OpCodes.Call, typeof( Enumerable ).GetMethod( nameof( Enumerable.ToArray ) ).MakeGenericMethod( typeof( T ) ) );
  il.Emit( OpCodes.Stloc_1 ); // Stores the sorted array
}
```

***A few things to note:***

- The provided expression is a selector that specifies which field (or property backing value) is used throughout the compiled method.
- This method does a lot more than just call `OrderByDescending()` and contains a lot of low level optimization. Excluding the sort, it is expected to run in under 40ns in most cases.

How can I take either the expression passed into the compile method or the `FieldInfo` to properly call `OrderByDescending()`?

Comment: why IL for building an expression tree, if you don't mind me asking? I'm very familiar with both expression trees and IL generation, but putting them together here seems very ... overkill? it isn't at all clear to me what you're trying to do, that couldn't be achieved by a simple `expression.Compile()` call. If the problem is changing the delegate type from `Func<T, double>` to `FilterDelegate<T>` (presumably testing against some constant `double`), that is something that could be achieved by expression tree voodoo, without requiring any IL.

Comment: @MarcGravell The excerpt of code I have posted is a part of a much larger function that I am compiling at runtime and contains a lot of optimizations. Sorting the array in descending order makes up a small fraction of what it does. IL is probably still a bit overkill given what I'm doing, but the rest of the emitted IL is complete and I would rather not completely re-do it if at all possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve with direct IL Generation; `OrderByDescending` takes a `Func<TSource, TKey>` parameter named "keySelector". So the only IL you can generate while still using this method would just be a regular method call that passes a "keySelector" argument to the `OrderByDescending` method unless you intend on re-implementing `OrderByDescending` in IL.

Is there a reason you need to drop down all the way to IL?

If this is for user level code, you can "Compile" the `expression` that would've been passed to this method and call `OrderByDescending()` normally e.g.

```
var expression = /* Select Field/Property Expression*/;
array.OrderByDescending(expression.Compile()).ToArray();
```

If this is framework/utility level code, you could potentially get away with using "Expression trees" without going all the way down to manual IL. e.g.

```
public static FilterDelegate<T> CreateDelegate<T>(Expression<Func<T, double>> expression)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<T>), "source");

    // Your `GetMethod` for OrderByDescending did not work for me,
    // so I'll just hand wave about this.
    var orderByDescMethod = typeof(Enumerable)
        .GetMethods()
        .Single(m => m.Name == nameof(Enumerable.OrderByDescending) &&
                     m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), typeof(double));

    var toArrayMethod = typeof(Enumerable)
        .GetMethod(nameof(Enumerable.ToArray))
        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));

    var orderByExpression = Expression.Call(orderByDescMethod, parameter, expression);
    var lambdaBody = Expression.Call(toArrayMethod, orderByExpression);
    var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<FilterDelegate<T>>(lambdaBody, parameter);

    return lambdaExpression.Compile();
}
```

---

If however, you still need to emit this directly via IL for some reason then something like the following can work.

```
public static FilterDelegate<T> CreateDelegate<T>(Expression<Func<T, double>> expression)
{
    // Your `GetMethod` for OrderByDescending did not work for me,
    // so I'll just hand wave about this.
    var orderByDescMethod = typeof(Enumerable)
                            .GetMethods()
                            .Single(m => m.Name == nameof(Enumerable.OrderByDescending) &&
                                         m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
                            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), typeof(double));

    var toArrayMethod = typeof(Enumerable)
                        .GetMethod(nameof(Enumerable.ToArray))
                        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));

    // TODO: if you don't already have one of these
    //       you'll probably want to pull this out and re-use it
    //       rather than making a new one for every delegate
    // TODO: if you do share a module builder I don't think it's thread-safe
    //       so this method will need sufficient locking/synchronization
    var dynamicAssemblyName = new AssemblyName { Name = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}" };
    var asm = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(dynamicAssemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
    var module = asm.DefineDynamicModule(dynamicAssemblyName.Name);

    // Create a class with a static field to hold our compiled expression
    var typeBuilder = module.DefineType(
        $"{Guid.NewGuid()}",
        TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class | TypeAttributes.Sealed | TypeAttributes.Serializable);

    var compiledExpressionField = typeBuilder.DefineField(
        "CompiledExpression",
        typeof(Func<T, double>),
        FieldAttributes.Static | FieldAttributes.Private);

    var holderType = typeBuilder.CreateType();

    var compiledExpression = expression.Compile();

    // Get the actual field after we've compiled the type
    var compiledExpressionFieldInfo = holderType.GetField(
        compiledExpressionField.Name,
        BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    // Store the compiled expression in the static field
    compiledExpressionFieldInfo.SetValue(null, compiledExpression);

    var newDelegate = new DynamicMethod($"{Guid.NewGuid()}",
        typeof(IOrderedEnumerable<T>),
        new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<T>) },
        typeof(ILGen), true);

    var il = newDelegate.GetILGenerator();

    // Load the array passed into the Delegate (T[])
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    // Load the compiled expression from a static field
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld, compiledExpressionFieldInfo);
    // Call .OrderByDescending()
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, orderByDescMethod);
    // Call .ToArray()
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, toArrayMethod);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret); // Stores the sorted array

    return (FilterDelegate<T>)newDelegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(FilterDelegate<T>));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out in a bit. Sorry if my post was unclear, but the method being compiled does much more than just call `OrderByDescending().ToArray()`; what is posted is just an excerpt of what wasn't working. This appears to be what I need though.